# comparing floats precisely after a cross product operation

Tags: math, floating-point, integer, geometry, precision

**This is about performing the following comparison precisely :**

```
CrossProduct(P - P0, P1 - P0) >, < or == 0
```

---

**Problem definition**

Given a set of grid points described by the following equation

```
P(x, y) = P(i, j) * delta = P(i * delta,  j * delta)
```

Where 0 <= i < resolution, 0<= j < resolution, delta = size / (resolution - 1)

Given a combination of any 3 distinct points P0, P1 and P2, it is desired to get an accurate boolean for the expressions:

```
CrossProduct(P1 - P0, P2 - P0) < 0

CrossProduct(P1 - P0, P2 - P0) > 0

CrossProduct(P1 - P0, P2 - P0) == 0
```

Where

```
CrossProduct(lhs, rhs) = lhs.x * rhs.y - lhs.y * rhs.x
```

---

**The Integer solution**

Those expressions can be calculated accuratly using integer math, if we describe the points using integers, as long as no overflows happen.

```
P = (i, j)
```

Since both i and j are >= 0, |i1 - i0| < resolution, therefore the CrossProduct will always have two arguments with coordinates no bigger than resolution. So, for no overflows :

```
a * b - c * d <= int.MaxValue
```

Where |a|, |b|, |c|, |d| < resolution

Which gives the following max resolution for no overflows :

```
maxResolution * maxResolution + maxResolution * maxResolution <= int.MaxValue
2 * maxResolution² <= int.MaxValue
maxResolution <= (int.MaxValue / 2)^(1/2)

For integers : maxResolution = 2^15 + 1
For longs : maxResolution = 2^31 + 1
```

Using integers work perfectly. Only downside is, points are stored as integers P(i, j), and every time access to the real point value is needed, it's required to use the initial formula to get the float value for that point P(x, y)

---

**Question**

Is it possible to achieve this using floats instead of integers? How?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but not easy. This article deals with Predicates for Computational Geometry
https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/robust.html

But if it is required for some geometric task, you can describe it. For example , if we want to make boolean operation on polygones, we don't require exact correct solution of lines intersections and orientation. We just need the repeatability of used predicates. It can be done mach mach easier.

Answer (score 0):

Floats store mantissas with 24 significant bits. That means that the relative error on the largest coordinate in your point set is at least 2^-24.

So, unless your problem has a non-uniform structure (larger point density close to the origin), it makes sense to rescale all coordinates to a [-2^24, 2^24]x[-2^24, 2^24] domain, and truncate to integer, forgetting the floats forever. There's even 7 spare bits of accuracy and you can map to [-2^31, 2^31]x[-2^31, 2^31], which is much more than you need.

Doing so, computing the signed area with 64 bits integers is done exactly and without overflow.

You may be reluctant to sacrifice some significant bits of the small coordinates, but in practical situations this should not matter.

If your coordinates are double, there are 2^53 mantissa bits, of which a large fraction must be noise. Then it makes sense to check the actual number of significant bits. You will realize that you have enough with... floats.

Answer (score -1):

**My float solution**

Imagine a small grid of 3x3 points truncated or rounded at 2nd digit:

```
(0.00, 1.00) (0.50, 1.00) (1.00, 1.00)
(0.00, 0.50) (0.50, 0.50) (1.00, 0.50)
(0.00, 0.00) (0.50, 0.00) (1.00, 0.00)
```

If we would interpret any float values further than the 2nd digit an error (because not all decimals can be described precisely with floats), then the CrossProduct operation, would have a minum absolute value of :

```
|CrossProduct((0.50 + error1, 0.00 + error2), (0.00 + error3, 0.50 + error4))| = 
(0.50)² + 0.50(error1 + error4) + error1 * error4 + error2 * error3
```

---

**Finding Epsilon**

If the float number was rounded, -0.005 <= error <= 0.005. If it was truncated, 0 <= error <= 0.01. Additionally, the error needs to consider that the actual float number may not be exacly 0.50, but 0.5000001f or 0.4999999f. So error gets an adjusment of +0.00000002f, giving an error of 0.0100002f for truncated numbers.

The result should be the same for either truncated or rounded, so we'll go with truncated for math simplicity to find the result, which will give the minimum value when :

```
CrossProduct((0.4899998, 0.00), (0.00, 0.4899998)) = 0.4899998² - 0.00² = 0.240099804
```

This means that any result from CrossProduct >= 0.240099804 is > 0, any result <= -0.240099804 is <0, and any result whose absolute value is < 0.240099804 is == 0.

Of course 0.240099804 has more precision than a float. It's float will be 0.2400998f. I'm actually not 100% sure here, Should we increase the error to 0.2400999f, or decrease it to 0.2400997f to consider the error for truncating the error? I'll just leave it as 0.2400998f for now. (Yes, this is minimal, but it could be the reason for a endless loop on the code, and a crash on the program, so it's important)

This gives the CrossProduct compare to zero formula :

```
if(CrossProduct >= ZERO) -> CrossProduct > 0
if(CrossProduct <= -ZERO) -> CrossProduct < 0
else -> CrossProduct == 0
```

Where

```
ZERO = (delta - maxError)²,
```

and

```
maxError = digit n of truncation + 2E-7.
```

---

**Not losing precision**

Additionally, for not losing precision during the CrossProduct operation, operations P1 - P0, lhs.x * rhs.y, lhs.y * rhs.x and lhs.x * rhs.y - lhs.y * rhs.x must not lose precision.

```
(float)(xmax +- xmin) == (real)(xmax +- xmin)    // float number sum of P0 and P1 equals real number sum of P0 and P1
(float)(xmax +- xmax) == (real)(xmax +- xmin)
(float)(xmin * ymin) == (real)(xmin * ymin)
(float)(xmax * ymax) == (real)(xmax * ymax)
(float)(xmax * ymin) == (real)(xmax * ymin)
```

Of course, for a square grid, xmax = ymax and xmin = ymin.

To satisfy the first condition (Sum), the difference of number of digits from xmax to xmin must not exceed 7. Which means : 123.4567 + 0.1234 = 123.5801 does not lose precision, whereas 123.4567 + 0.12345 = 123.5801 != 123.58015.

More than that, the sum of xmax with xmax, must also not exceed the number of digits of xmax, because 500.0000 + 500.0000 = 1000.000. This number itself is correct, but it has threspassed the number of digits of xmax, which could lead to erros on the next step of xmax * ymin.

This far, we haven't lost precision on the P1-P0 and P2 - P0 part of the CrossProduct operation. There's still more left. CrossProduct(P4 = P1-P0, P5 = P2 - P0) must also not lose precision.

For operation a * b to maintain precision on a float,

```
number of digits of a + number of digits of b <= 7
```

Meaning

```
number of digits a <= 3    // Number of digits a == number of digits b
```

Now, it becomes tricky at operation a * b - c * d. The worst case scenario here, is when a = b = xmax, c = d = xmin.

If both a and b have n digits each, a * b will have 2 * n digits at most.
The new digits can appear either to the left, moving the precision to the left, or to the right, moving the precision to the left.

Worst case scenario happens when a * b moves 3 digits to the left, and c * d moves 3 digits to the right.

So we would need 12 precision digits to do operation xmax * xmax + xmin * xmin without losing precision if xmax had 3 digits of precision > 1 and xmin had 3 digits < 1.

This leaves us with 1 digit only for 32-bit floats.

Anything less than 3 digits is unacceptable in terms of precision, so we have to try with 64-bit floats.

Doing the same math again, 64-bit floats, with 16 digits, will allow us to use at most 4 digits of precision on our points.

Summing up, It's needed to use 64-bit floats, with 4 digits of precision at most, and the leftmost digit must not exceed 5. Looks like a hell of a trouble for avoiding integers.

---

I really hope i didn't mess up on anything, but i can tell i'm not 100% sure if the above math is correcy for floats. It sure looks correct when thinking of real numbers.

I hope this helps people understand how to deal with float inacuraccy when precision is needed. Note that this method can be extended to other operations using similar epsilon and precision analysis. Keep in mind that inaccuracy sums up very fast when performing multiple chained operations. For a single cross product, our 16 digits precision double went down to only 4 digits.

Also, if anyone find a mistake or think of something i havent considered or missed on any of the above, please let us know so we can fix it. AS far as i've tested, it all works fine, both the integer and the 64-bit float methods. (Dont do this with 32-bit floats!)

Edit: Actually, when the result is between - ZERO and ZERO, we can't tell 100% it's zero. It's a doubt zone. It can be said with 100% accuracy when > ZERO and when < -ZERO. So another method would be needed for this doubt zone.

### There is also a zone where there is 100% certainty that the result is zero, which is when result < maxError² (Differs from the previously defined ZERO by delta)

**Conclusions**

If the above method for comparing cross product using float is absolutely correct, there are still a few pros and cons of going with floats over integers.

A first downside of using floats over integers, is the early truncation or rounding, which could make point 0.3333333f become 0.3300000 +- error.

If the precision of the final point result is not nearly as important as not having an error, and it's worth the trouble / performance of having to reuse the P(i,j) to P(x,y) formula every single time, then this should not be a problem.

On the other side, it's possible to achieve a very very high precision using 64-bit integers over 64-bit floats. Max integer resolution was calculated as 2^15, which gives a unitary delta of (1/2^15) = 3.05E-5. That is already more significant digits than 64-bit floats will give. 64-bit integers will yield even more precision : 4.65E-10.

Myself, i'll probably stick with the intergers solution, and accept the trouble / performance of recalculating the float point from the int point every single time. But anyway, this is probably going ot be useful for a lot of people having trouble with floats

Comment: The first paragraph below the title “Finding epsilon” is nonsense. First, there is no reason to believe that the approximation that has been made representing the real values as floats is only 1/2 ULP or 1 ULP. That depends on the previous computations. More importantly, this loss of accuracy is already done! It's in the past. It's too late now. What you should concern yourself with is the loss of accuracy of the operations that are under your control, the additions and multiplications of cross-product.

Comment: Second “the error needs to consider that the actual float number may not be exacly 0.50, but 0.5000001f or 0.4999999f” is doubly nonsensical. **YOU ARE ALREADY DISCUSSING AN ERROR IN REPRESENTING A REAL NUMBER WITH FLOATING POINT.** You don't need to add to that a secondary error “because floats are inexact”. THE REPRESENTATION ERROR IS WHAT YOUR EQUATIONS ARE ABOUT.

Comment: If you are interested in floating-point you should read http://lipforge.ens-lyon.fr/www/crlibm/documents/cern.pdf (free) or better, the “Handbook of Floating-Point Arithmetic” (expensive but you might find an illegal PDF for free). And if you don't have time for that, the TLDR is that the floating-point types you use are represented in binary, and that you should simply take that into account instead of computing errors on the error.

Comment: The first consequence of the fact that the floating-point types you use are binary is that 0.5 is represented exactly, unlike 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8 and 0.9.

Comment: The fact that you find that IEEE 754 double-precision performs worse than 32-bit integers is another hint. Generally, if your double-precision computation is unable to do handle gracefully problems that could as well have been tackled with hypothetical 53-bit integers, you are using floating-point wrong.

Comment: For the accurate computation of `a*b + c*d` in floating-point arithmetic see [this paper](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/AnalysisCornea_final.pdf)